# How can I convert String to Boolean in python?

Tags: python, string, boolean, return-value, transformation

I need to get the value True and False from the string "True and False".

Comment: Please include the code you've tried and add some information regarding the language or tools you're using so that this post meets the guidelines for asking questions in the help center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: The language is python, I hope that the problem is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `eval` function to test the condition and then the `str` function to go back:

```py
>>> condition = 'True and False'
>>> test = eval(condition)
>>> test
False
>>> type(test)
<class 'bool'>
>>> result = str(test)
>>> result
'False'
>>> type(result)
<class 'str'>
```